# I'm trying to get word frequency on tweet text from a csv file using pandas value counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Here's my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import string

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()


def remove_stopwords(df_text):
    words = [w for w in df_text if w not in stopwords.words('english')]
    return words

def word_lemmatizer(df_text):
    lem_text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in df_text]
    return lem_text

#works fine from here
df = pd.read_csv('amazonfresh-test.csv', encoding='utf-8', converters={'text': str})


df['text'].apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower()))
df['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
df['text'].apply(lambda x: word_lemmatizer(x))

#to here

#this is where I have issues
data_count = df['test'].apply(pd.value_counts())

data_count.to_excel("amazonfresh-test.xlsx")
```

It takes forever to run and I'm simply trying to strip and split the strings in each row of a text column and then have the overall word counts to show word frequency.

[Here is what the csv looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIUhm.png)

[Here is the new csv with words in their own cell, still struggling to get the value_count on this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6fIC.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `'amazonfresh-test.csv'`?

Comment: Yes, just did @Phillyclause89

Comment: Thanks for the csv screenshot. Where do you get the `'test'` column from in `data_count = df['test'].apply(pd.value_counts())`? I'm not seeing that as a column existing in your source csv and I don't see you create such a column anywhere in your code before you use the `pandas.Series.apply` method on it.

Comment: @Phillyclause89 that must have been a typo, it was to reference the 'text' column in the csv

Comment: Was that typo causing your issue, or is the behavior you noted in this question occurring without the typo being present in the code?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 it is occurring without the typo being present. I'm able to lemmatize, remove stopwords, and tokenize without too much of an issue. But I have a problem simply trying to get the value count on the text in the column

Comment: also I'm not familiar with `pandas.value_counts` method. There is `pandas.Series.value_counts`, but I'm not sure if this is what you want to use here. are you just trying to get a  count of each token remaining after removing the stop words? maybe try: `data_count = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(x))`?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 the program seems to be taking an absurdly long amount of time to run, any inkling why?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 yes, just trying to count the remaining tokens, the script you suggested only outputs numbers

Comment: I think I understand what you are after here. It took me a second to get all the nltk packages installed, but I'm up and running with your script now. Can you confirm that you are actually hitting the "#this is where I have issues" line and does the line below that actually have `data_count = df['text'].apply(pd.value_counts())` or are there other typos in that line? as written I get `TypeError: value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'` when I try to run it. How did you identify that this line is your bottle neck? Are you sure it isn't one of the other `.apply` calls?

Comment: So two ideas after playing around with this. 1) keep in mind that `pandas.Series.apply` is not an inplace method by default. I think you want to do `df['text'] = df['text'].apply(func)` in those three lines where it looks like you want to tokonize and filter the data in the text column. 2) I think you want to remove the caller from the `pd.value_counts` function in the `data_count = df['test'].apply(pd.value_counts())` line. try doing `data_count = df['test'].apply(pd.value_counts)`?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 okay so I was able to output a csv with each word split into its own cell, how would I then use the value counts? I'll attach the new csv in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair amount of back in forth in the comments with OP, I decided it would be best to summarize my suggestions here.

The first issue is there are two typos in `data_count = df['test'].apply(pd.value_counts())`.

That line should actually be `data_count = df['text'].apply(pd.value_counts)`.

`df['test']` will raise a `KeyError` since there is no `'test'` column in OP's `pandas.DataFrame`.  The other typo is an argumentless call of `pandas.value_counts` into the caller of `pandas.Series.apply` method.  This would raise a `TypeError` due to the fact that the `pandas.value_counts` function requires at least one argument. But this is easily fixed by removing the caller since the point of the `pandas.Series.apply` method is to have it call the function for us using each value in the series as an argument.

The next issue I noticed is with the other three calls of the `pandas.Series.apply` method:

```
df['text'].apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower()))
df['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
df['text'].apply(lambda x: word_lemmatizer(x))
```

These three lines are written as though `pandas.Series.apply` is an inplace method, which it is not. To actually have these change the `pandas.DataFrame` object assigned to `df`, one needs to actually use assignment here:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower()))
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(remove_stopwords)
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(word_lemmatizer)
```

Additionally, the lambda expression is only needed in the first call to do the `x.lower()` part, since `remove_stopwords` and `word_lemmatizer` are both taking the value as is, we don't need the extra lambdas.  Finally, all three lines could be condensed into a single call of `pandas.Series.apply` since there are applying these functions to the same values:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(
    lambda x: word_lemmatizer(
        remove_stopwords(
            tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower())
        )
    )
)
```

The full code that I hope OP was able to put together from my comments should look something like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import pandas as pd

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()


def remove_stopwords(df_text):
    words = [w for w in df_text if w not in stopwords.words('english')]
    return words


def word_lemmatizer(df_text):
    lem_text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in df_text]
    return lem_text


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', converters={'text': str}, sep="\t")

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(
    lambda x: word_lemmatizer(
        remove_stopwords(
            tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower())
        )
    )
)

data_count = df['text'].apply(pd.value_counts)

data_count.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

This excel file created should look something like this.

[image]
*Note: The output displayed in my screenshot is from running this code on a single column csv that consists of the first 100 sentences of the book Dune, I didn't bother recreating the csv shown in OP's screenshot, since the only-thing that should matter is that there is a column with a bunch of English words named 'text'*

With all this now documented in this answer, OP still has one unassered comment:

> @Phillyclause89 okay so I was able to output a csv with each word split into its own cell, how would I then use the value counts? I'll attach the new csv in the original post.

My recommendation is that `pandas.value_counts` gets used as I have shown in the above code example (inside `pandas.Series.Apply` and without calling it.) From there you can use various agg methods like sum to find the counts of words across all rows:

```
agg_data_count = data_count.sum().sort_values(0,ascending=False)
agg_data_count.to_excel("sums.xlsx")
```

Opening sums.xlsx we can get a nice list of our words and how many times they appear in the whole data set:
[image]

Comment: also realized that df['text'].value_counts() works too, thanks for your help!